# XStream deserialization issue from custom method

Tags: java, xstream

My Props class:

```
public class Props {
    private static String name; 
    private static float price;

    //normal getters and setters;
}
```

my XML

```
<root>
<Props>
  <name>Test1</name>
  <ownedBy>NULL</ownedBy>
  <price>1000</price>
</Props>
<Props>
  <name>Test2</name>
  <ownedBy>NULL</ownedBy>
  <price>1000</price>
</Props>
</root>
```

now when I call `in.readObject();` twice (in being my object input stream) I get the error:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Could not set field class  
com.mwerner.main.Props.name : null : Could not set field class 
com.mwerner.main.Props.name : null
```

I tried the code in a separate project and it worked beautifully. now in the bigger main project I am calling the entire thing in a custom method called `initProps();` That's when it all went to hell. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I wrote a custom converter based on the XStream tutorial. For the unmarshal method I simply added a bunch more `reader.MoveDown(); setvalue... reader.MoveUp();` levels for the remaining fields.